# cant initialize var variable more than once

Tags: c#, var, initializer, livecharts

hi i have a var variable and i need initialize it based on if statement this is my code:

```
var series = new ColumnSeries{};
if(integer == 0)
  series = new LineSeries{};
else if (integer == 1)
  series = new PieSeries{};
else if (integer == 2)
  series = new AreaSeries{};
```

but it get error that i cant initialize variable more than once, so how i can initialize this variable more than once? i need change my chart type based on if statement so i tried this way.

Comment: You can initialize it more than once, but it has to be of the same type. So if `LineSeries`,`PieSeries`,`AreaSeries`are not  `ColumnSeries` this won't compile.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so what should I do?

Comment: They all look to be under the abstract class LiveCharts.Wpf.Series

Comment: You could make a series base class that ColumnSeries, LineSeries, PieSeries and AeraSeries extend. Cast the base var to the extension class as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var` is implicit typing; in your case it assumes that it should be a `ColumnSeries`.

To use a base class (so other derived classes can be assigned to it) you could cast the initialized object or just don't use var.

```
Series series = new ColumnSeries(); //Preferred. var is just a bad choice here
var series = (Series)new ColumnSeries();
```

Answer (score 0):

They need to be the same type. Program to a common Interface for all of them, something like ISeries.

Comment: It is more accurate to say they need to be the same type or part of the type's inheritance family.

Answer (score 0):

By instantiating it as a `ColumnSeries` to begin with, you will be unable to assign it to a different type later (unless it's a type that implements `ColumnSeries`).

Instead, you can declare it as a common base type (or interface) and then later assign it to any type that implements that base class or interface:

```
Series series = 
    integer == 0
        ? new LineSeries()
        : integer == 1
            ? new PieSeries()
            : integer == 2
                ? new AreaSeries()
                :  new ColumnSeries();
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I recommend against this, you can use the type `dynamic` which can change it's type on usage, so you can do:

```
dynamic series = new ColumnSeries{};

if(integer == 0)
   series = new LineSeries{};
else if (integer == 1)
   series = new PieSeries{};
else if (integer == 2)
   series = new AreaSeries{};
```

And it's type will change to `LineSeries()`, `PieSeries`, and `AreaSeries` respectively. This also means that the compiler won't know what functions it has when compiling, so you get a lot less safety and more execution errors, and less IDE/Auto-complete support too.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the best use of var and object, I think we could do something like this:

`var series = new object();`

Keep in mind though that after you assign something to it, it will remain an object and you will have to cast it to the type you want.

```
if(integer == 0)
    series = new LineSeries{};
else if (integer == 1)
    series = new PieSeries{};
else if (integer == 2)
    series = new AreaSeries{};
```

Lets say the first condition is satisfied in order to get access to series properties you need to cast it to a LineSeries.

You could also do:

```
dynamic series = new object();
```

In this case once you have assigned something to it, it wont be an object so no need for casting but as [Austin Bryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3800096/austinwbryan) mentioned in his answer above you loose other compiler and IDE benefits.